# Creating Form Inside the Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to Visual Studio 2010 and I'm planning to create a Timekeeping system. I'm just want to ask how could I create a form that compose 2 forms in it. For example, if I will click a button it will open a new form inside a form. Please help. Thanks

Comment: dont nest a form inside another. you will only cause more problems

Comment: On the other hand, see [Hans Passant - turn a form into a child control](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7692113/199364).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to work with `MDI (Multiple Document Interface)`, have alook at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mdiformstutorial.aspx) that might help.

Answer (score 8):

```
Form formA = new Form();
formA.IsMdiContainer = true;

Form formB = new Form();
formB.MdiParent = formA;
formB.Show();
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create custom form, remove all borders, and toolbars to make it look as closely to a panel as possible. Then make that new custom form a MdiContainer / MDI-panel and show forms in that panel, something like the code below will do the job

Mdi-Panel definiton:

public class MdiClientPanel : Panel
{
    private Form mdiForm;
    private MdiClient ctlClient = new MdiClient();

```
public MdiClientPanel()
{
    base.Controls.Add(this.ctlClient);
}

public Form MdiForm
{
    get
    {
        if (this.mdiForm == null)
        {
            this.mdiForm = new Form();
            /// set the hidden ctlClient field which is used to determine if the form is an MDI form
            System.Reflection.FieldInfo field = typeof(Form).GetField("ctlClient", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
            field.SetValue(this.mdiForm, this.ctlClient);
        }
        return this.mdiForm;
    }
}
```

}

Usage:

```
/// mdiChildForm is the form that should be showed in the panel
/// mdiClientPanel is an instance of the MdiClientPanel
myMdiChildForm.MdiParent = mdiClientPanel1.MdiForm;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is a very easy way:

```
    Form1 form= new Form1 ();
    form.TopLevel = false;
    this.Controls.Add(form);
    form.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [MDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface) interface will do what you want..

[Here's](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ggaganesh/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp11272005225843PM/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp.aspx) a tutorial to do that.