# C# Windows Forms - How to create or open a popup window on Main Window like WinRAR?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a window in my Main Windows Form. 
Like: [An Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsZMI.png) and [Other Example (Just Minimized)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6U4k.png) or WinRAR. Is that possible on Windows Forms? 
**(Note: If my grammar bad, sorry. I'm not English person.)**

Comment: MDI would probably be the simplest to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited to make the answer less vague / link only*

MDI is what you're looking for. First you will need to set your main form's (parent) IsMDIContainer property to true.

After that, you can add a MainMenu, which will give you the option for opening a child form within the parent form. You will need to add a second form to your project to use as a template for the child forms. You will then have to create an instance of that form.

```
//Create a new instance of the MDI child template form
Form2 chForm = new Form2(); 

//Set parent form for the child window 
chForm.MdiParent=this;

//Display the child window
chForm.Show();
```

Use this link for more in depth information on MDI Parent and Child forms:
[Form Inside a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463894/creating-form-inside-the-form)

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: I tried this but application is throw error: ArgumentException on `chForm.MdiParent=this;`

Comment: I'm used chForm.MdiParent=this.MdiParent; and problem was solved.

Comment: Works fine on my end...
Follow these steps:
1) Create new WinForm application 
2) Change Form1 IsMdiContainer property to True
3) Add new windows form (form 2)
4) Paste above code in to Form1_Load

Comment: Oh well good. Glad this answer worked for you.