# Set Location for new form

Tags: c#, windows

I use below code to make lightbox effect and it works as i expected. However if i move the parent form it still pop-ups on the center of the screen.

```
// Execute this code from parent form
Form f = new Form();
f.ShowInTaskbar = false;
f.BackColor = Color.Black;
f.Size = this.Size;
f.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
f.StartPosition = this.StartPosition;
f.Opacity = 0.6;
f.Show();
```

So i changed the above code like below;

```
f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

However it still doesn't pop-up  center of the parent form.

Also i tried below, It didn't work too;

```
f.SetBounds(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y,this.Width, this.Height);
```

I already tried the solutions here;

[Show a child form in the centre of Parent form in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944897/show-a-child-form-in-the-centre-of-parent-form-in-c-sharp)

They also didn't work.

What i want to do is, creating a second form with the same size and same location.

Comment: @stuard It doesn't duplicated topic. Please remove this mark. I also that topic's answer and they didn't work. Also i already said that in my question. Read my question first.

Comment: I doesn't seem to me that the problem is solved with the existent question, since he defined the "children" form's StartPosition property the same way as the solution points out.

Comment: check this one out instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463894/creating-form-inside-the-form 
because i'm inclined to assume that your created form isn't exactly a children of your parent form and that's why you are not achieving your desired behaviour.

Comment: @AndréB you are definitely right. When i change  f.show() to f.showdialog();. It worked.

Comment: You never set the parent of f.. as a result your current form is not the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing this line;

```
f.Show();
```

to  this line, It worked;

```
f.ShowDialog();
```