# When I load form inside panel textbox default properties get lost

Tags: vb.net, forms, textbox

when I load form inside panel using code

```vb
With Form_brand
    .TopLevel = False
    Panel2.Controls.Add(Form_brand)
    .BringToFront()
    .Show()
End With
```

textbox inside form does not show its default behaviour like
when i click inside textbox cursor show at starting of the text instead of place where I click the mouse. Another problem is that when I move mouse pointer with clicking mouse button text should be selected but this does not happen.

If I open form simply using code

```vb
Form_Brand.show()
```

textbox shows it default behaviour. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Winforms - Embedding form inside a form or container causes form controls to behave differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481068/winforms-embedding-form-inside-a-form-or-container-causes-form-controls-to-beh)

Comment: Create a UserControl instead of a Form. You can design it visually in the designer exactly like a Form.

Comment: Can you post sample code hoe to open a usercontrol within panel using button. Sorry as I am new in vb.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseDown
    TextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        TextBox1.SelectionLength = TextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location) - TextBox1.SelectionStart + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UserControl` instead of a Form. You can design it visually in the designer exactly like a Form.

Example of adding a UserControl to a panel

```vb
Dim uc = New MyUserControl() ' But please, give it a better name!
Panel2.Controls.Add(uc)
```

Note that you don't have to set a `TopLevel` property nor to call `BringToFront()` or `Show()`.